# WAP to print first 10 multiples of 5, but skip the multiples of 3.This error message is being shown : bad operand types for binary operator '&&'

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i){
            System.out.println((i*5)&&(i%3!=0));
        }
     }
}
```

What is wrong with line 5?

Comment: What do you intend the `&&` to do?

Comment: that && is not the operand to use. It's the logical AND, not something to add output together;. Likely, what you mean to do is: (i*5) + " " + (i%3i=0)

Comment: @Stultuske going on the description in the title, there should be no operator there: there should just be the `i*5`, and then an if statement around the line.

Comment: PrintStream Class having overloaded method of println() on all datatypes, so datatype should matched during method call.
and I agree with @AndyTurner

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` is for combining two logical values (boolean-values: true/false-values). It sadly cannot combine with numbers (at least in java)

In your provided code the `(i*5)` results in a number, the `(i%3!=0)` in a boolean value. Java doesn't know how to combine those with `&&`, that's why you get an error.

A way to solve the error and get the code to work as intended is as follows:

```java
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            if(i % 3 != 0){
                System.out.println(i * 5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to use an if-statment to check for multiples of 3, the `&&`-operator is reserved to only combine boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

&& is a logical operator and therefore you are getting this error.

As per your requirement, you can add an if condition before System.out.println() to check if that multiple is not divisible by 3.

Comment: I think OP might struggle to understand what you are saying here: perhaps show an example.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax issue with the line `System.out.println((i*5)&&(i%3!=0));` has already been explained: logical AND `&&` expects only boolean operands, while `i*5` is an `int`.

However, there is another issue with the loop which needs to maintain a separate counter for the number of prints to ensure that 10 numbers are printed:

```java
for (int i = 5, j = 1; j <= 10; i += 5) {
    if (i % 3 != 0) { // ignore multiple of 3
        System.out.println(i);
        j++; 
    }
}
```